# MySQL Tree From path

Tags: mysql

I want to display a tree structure in MYSQL with this reference

```
+----+--------------+----------------+
| id |  name        | Path           |
| 751| ledger 1     |   751/         |
| 752| l sub        |   751/752/     |
| 753| l sub1.2     |   751/752/753/ |
| 754| l sub2       |   751/754/     |
| 756| l Sub1.3     |   751/752/756/ |
| 757| l Sub2.1     |   751/754/757/ |
+----+--------------+----------------+
```

i just need the answer as

```
ledger 1
     l sub
         l sub1.2
         L Sub1.3
     l sub2 
         l Sub2.1
```

Comment: i've tries much.. but negative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with concatenating spaces before name:

```
SELECT
  CASE  LENGTH(Path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Path, '/', '')) 
    WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT('   ', name)
    WHEN 3 THEN CONCAT('      ', name)
    WHEN 4 THEN CONCAT('         ', name)
    WHEN 5 THEN CONCAT('            ', name)
    WHEN 6 THEN CONCAT('               ', name)
    -- ... to max depth
    ELSE name
  END AS result
FROM tab
ORDER BY path;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19299e/1/0)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Using `REPEAT`:

```
SELECT
  CASE  
    WHEN LENGTH(Path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Path, '/', '')) > 1 
    THEN CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', LENGTH(Path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Path, '/', ''))-1 ),name)
    ELSE name
  END AS result
FROM tab
ORDER BY path;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43a94/3/0)**</kbd>

Another approach (as `@Mchl` proposed in comment) is to calculate `DEPTH` and do formatting in application:

```
SELECT *,
   LENGTH(Path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Path, '/', '')) AS depth
FROM tab
ORDER BY path;
```

Comment: it is not full functioned.. if names are some what big in length,the result name is not the not the full name

Comment: Seriously: why not just select a depth as a number and do all the formatting in the application which gets this data?

Comment: @Mchl Yes seriously. Your proposal is one way to go, my is another. I wanted to use something like `REPLICATE(string, num)` but cannot find equivalent in MySQL so I've used case.

Comment: SELECT
  CASE  
    WHEN LENGTH(Path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Path, '/', '')) > 1 
    THEN CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', LENGTH(Path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Path, '/', ''))-1 ),name)
    ELSE name
  END AS result
FROM tab
ORDER BY path;


it's better